# Import issue with docker's libcontainer

Tags: go

When using the docker's libcontainer (specifically the network part), I get an `undefined` error while building using `go build` on my project.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    ...
    "github.com/docker/libcontainer/network"
)

func SetIP(a Address) (err error) {
   ...
   err = network.SetInterfaceIp(a.Link, a.IP)
   ....
}
```

The error itself:

`./addresses.go:170: undefined: network.SetInterfaceIp`

I've checked inside the library itself and I can find this so called function.

Comment: You probably have an old version of "github.com/docker/libcontainer/network" installed. Try updating that first.

Comment: Are you perchance not building this on Linux? This file is not built on OSX/Windows

Comment: @JimB: I've checked out HEAD on master for libcontainer. Same result.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer as a matter of fact, I'm on OSX, I'll try to build it on a VM and post the results.

Comment: @Ketouem: look at the source file, it's set `build +linux`. The docker client is the only part that runs on non-linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was building on OSX, which cannot be done when using `libcontainer`. After using a debian VM the whole project was built correctly.

Kudos to @JimB and @Not_a_Golfer for the hints.